# Make sure that an event execute after the actions of another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say that I've a file where I bind an event to some inputs, for parse and format date with moment.js, for example:

```
// plugins.js
$('.date').on('focusout', function() {
    var thisInput = $(this);
    thisInput.val( moment(thisInput.val()).format('YYYY-MM-DD') );
});
```

In my html file I've a script after the `plugins.js` call, in this script I use the parsed date to calculate the age from the date, assuming that the function has already executed in `plugins.js`:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="birth-date-input">Birth date</label>
        <input type="text" id="birth-date-input" class="date">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="age">Age</label>
        <input type="text" id="age">
    </div>
</form>

<script src="plugins.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#birth-date-input').on('focusout', function() {
            var thisInputVal = $(this).val();
            var birthDate = moment(thisInputVal, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
            var age = moment().diff(birthDate, 'years');
            $('#age').val( age );
        });
    });
</script>
```

In my ideal word the `.val()` of the second script would be the assigned in the first, the parsed date. But the fact is that in both cases the value is the same, the only way I could make this work was with a dirty `setTimeout()`.

```
$('#birth-date-input').on('focusout', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var thisInputVal = $(this).val();
        var birthDate = moment(thisInputVal, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
        var age = moment().diff(birthDate, 'years');
        $('#age').val( age );
    }, 100);
});
```

Is there an alternative way to do this? To make sure that an event execute after the actions of another one [without setTimeout]...

Comment: Can you elaborate the problem? Why are you not merging the two events?

Comment: Can you combine them into one event handler? Or call one event handler from the other?

Comment: Do you really need the first listener of the same event? what about custom event and than trigger it when age is set?

Comment: I would like not no modify the script in the file, the purpose of it isn't calculate ages or stuff, just to parse the given date. Anyhow, I'll be happy to hear that there is a way to extend the event, or promises...

Comment: @Cheery that's a really good idea! Really good!

Answer (score 0):

You can call function which you want to execute first inside the second function before any other code. SO it has to execute first like.

```css
function a()
{

  alert("first");
return true;
}
function b
{

  b();
  alert("second");
}
```

or you can set an hidden variable on execution of first functin and check whether it is set or not in second one.